# Skipping an iteration in for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, iteration

Is there an effective way to skip an iteration in a for loop?

I have a big dataset that consists of option prices on the S&P 500 index. The dataset ranges from 1992 to 2009. Now, in total, I have 3481 quoting dates that I have stored in certain vector that I call `QDvector`. I'm only interested in the quoting dates from 2008 until 2009. For each quoting date, I run a certain program. The quoting dates of interest are from 3290 until 3481. However, in some special cases (very few), the program does not work due to lack of stock data. How do I skip these iterations in the for loop?

For instance, suppose that I have

```
for index = 3290:3481
    [...]
end
```

and suppose that I do not want to take the `index == 3389` into account. How do I skip this iteration?

- I can use a while loop, but I really do not want to take this index in consideration at all, since I also have to plot certain parameters and I want to skip the parameters corresponding with `index == 3389`.
- I can remove the quoting date from the `QDvector`. I do not prefer this approach since I have to change too many other variables as well.

I'm simply looking for a good way to skip certain iterations without any consequences.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [`continue`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) statement allows to do that.

```
for index = 3290:3481
    [...]
    continue;    % wherever applicable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the index and execute your code whenever it's not found.

```
for index = 3290:3481
    if index != 3389
        [...]
    end
end
```

Without an else statement, nothing will happen when the statement is false, effectively skipping the index.

Alternatively:

```
for index = 3290:3481
    if index == 3389
        continue
    else
        [...]
    end
end
```

Is slightly less efficient, since the check will be run and in most cases, progress onto the else. But for only 191 passes, it probably won't be noticeable.

Comment: you dont need the else, the continue will skip the rest of the loop body

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677256/if-vs-continue-statement-in-a-for-loop/36677535#36677535) for a performance comparison